# How to fix broken png images on my site?

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap-3, png, broken-image

Images on my webpage are displaying as broken. I have the file path to image correct in my coding, and I can even pull up the image in my browser, just not on the webpage. The file path to the image below is: /site/img/slide02.png . This is just an example, all of the images on my site are broken. Any suggestions as to what might be causing this or how to fix?

```
<img src="img/slide02.png" class="img-responsive"></div>
```

Comment: Can you describe the folder structure of where the images are and where the html pages that reference the images are as well.

Comment: The folder "site" contains: html files, a css file, a folder "img". Folder "img" contains: png files. I have 3 html files that are referring to images in the "img" folder. Is this helpful?

Comment: Maybe it will help to say "<img src="./img/slide02.png" ...>" to indicate the file location relative to your .html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my hosting platform, I had the permissions set to 644 but the actual image properties had permissions set to read-only. 
I went to the images on my local device and went to properties and changed the permission from read-only.
Once I changed that and uploaded them again, the images were no longer broken.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your webpages in the same directory/folder that the img directory resides in? They will need to be for how you currently have things set up.

Comment: yes. my html file's directory is: site/index.html. my image's directory is: site/img/slide02.png.

Comment: Is it possible that we can view this website?

Comment: yes! I wasn't sure if I could link to it. With that in mind, the name of the site folder is "imancarr.sume" instead of "site". The site is imancarr.sume.andreaivy.com.

Comment: What do you have the permissions of the image files set to? Can you set them to 644?

Comment: Permissions are set to "read". I am not sure how to set them manually. I am looking into that now.

Comment: I am seeing the error message, "Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe". Try creating a .htaccess file in the root of your directory structure.

Comment: I have a .htaccess file. I'm going to see if I can disable it.